Why are the values of $i being printed during the loop iteration in PowerShell?
        $i = 0
    foreach ($key in $variationjson.PSObject.Properties.Name) {
        $value = $variationjson.$key * 100
        $series.Points.AddXY("", $value)
        $series.Points[$i].Label = $key
        if ($value -lt 0) {
            $series.Points[$i].Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red
        } else {
            $series.Points[$i].Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::Green
        }
        $i++  # Incrementa o índice
    }

The values of $i are being printed to the console during execution, but they shouldn't be.
I don't know what else to try; I even attempted using Out-Null or changing to $i = $i + 1, but it keeps getting printed.
series are from Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
$variationjson is a simple json object like {title_name:value...}
output:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18...

solved, I just needed to put Out-Null in every .add of any object in the entire script.
the topic here where I found the solution
